# How to block dots "." in an iptables rule?

Tags: iptables

I have this rule in my iptables to block domains ending with `.watch`:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP -m string --string ".watch" --algo kmp
```

But the problem is that the `.` cannot be matched. So the line above does not match anything. But if I remove the dot from `.watch` to `watch` it works okay.

How can I block the dots "." in iptables rules?

Comment: This is not the proper way for doing this. If you are expecting to block DNS queries for the domain, there are no dots to match in the query packets because of the way DNS protocol is implemented.

Comment: Thank you @Tero. Do you know a better way of doing it than using `Dnsmasq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, this seems correct, but your approach is not suitable for this purpose. The [string patch](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.18) matches a string anywhere in the packet:

- You are dropping any packet that has `watch` or `.watch` anywhere. This is likely to cause false positives, and even introduces a new vector for denial of service attacks.
- It cannot handle encrypted traffic. It is unable to block [majority of web traffic](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-httpsdefault).
- Although you have relatively good options for the matching algorithm (`bm` Boyer–Moore & `kmp` Knuth–Pratt–Morris), the use of the string filter can still be compute intensive.

The documentation explicitly warns against this, too:

> Please do use this match with caution. A lot of people want to use
> this match to stop worms, along with the DROP target. This is a major
> mistake. It would be defeated by any IDS evasion method.
>
> In a similar fashion, a lot of people have been using this match as a
> mean to stop particular functions in HTTP like POST or GET by dropping
> any HTTP packet containing the string POST. Please understand that
> this job is better done by a filtering proxy. Additionally, any HTML
> content with the word POST would get dropped with the former method.
> This match has been designed to be able to queue to userland
> interesting packets for better analysis, that's all. Dropping packet
> based on this would be defeated by any IDS evasion method.

There are better alternatives for what you are trying to achieve:

- DNS based filtering. Any DNS server can do this. E.g., [Dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is a common lightweight DNS forwarder: you could just add `address=/watch/0.0.0.0` to its configuration.
- Web proxy based filtering.

Comment: Thank you. What I am really trying to say is that the `.` cannot be blocked. For example, blocking string `"com"` blocks `serverfault.com`; but using `".com"` does not block the same website.

Comment: I can understand that. What I am trying to tell is that you should stop enhancing your hammer for screwing and use a screwdriver, instead. :)

Comment: It turned out that `/etc/hosts.deny` is deprecated. https://askubuntu.com/a/23225

Comment: Thanks! I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

DNS names are encoded as length prefixed labels (see [rfc 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) for details), so you need to use `--hex-string "|05|watch|00|"` to match names ending in `.watch` (note that the length is written as 2 hexadecimal digits, eg `serverfault.com` would be encoded as `"|0b|serverfault|03|com|00|"`). Note that this  should be combined with `-p udp` and `--destination-port 53` (or 5353 if matching `.local` addresses), otherwise it's likely to match lots of other unrelated packets.

DNS queries can also be made over TCP, but filtering TCP is more complex and existing comments about encrypted requests, and suggestions about using application level filtering with a DNS and/or web proxy still apply.

Comment: Not only encryption obscures TCP, but fragmentation and segmentation already enough to defeat string match like this. Send the TCP request in at least two segments split in the middle of the word "watch" and you're done.

Comment: See also https://blog.cloudflare.com/bpf-the-forgotten-bytecode/ for other ways to match DNS packets